# how to fix this ("this.http.post(...).map(...).concatMap is not a function")?

Tags: angular

I've got this error after upgrading my angular project

> this.http.post(...).map(...).concatMap is not a function

[image]

and here is my code that cause the error

```
return this.http.post(apiURL, body, options)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .concatMap(response => {
            // Check if the API_TOKEN is expired.
            if (response.error.code == APIErrorCode.API_TOKEN_EXPIRED || response.error.code == 499) {
                // Expired! Check max attempts.
                if (attempts < MAX_REQUEST_ATTEMPT) {
                    console.log("API_TOKEN expired.");
                    return this.requestAPIToken().delay(500)
                            .concatMap(response => this.doPost(api, body, attempts + 1));
                }
                console.log("API_TOKEN expired, request attempt limit reached!");
            }
            return Observable.of(response);
        })
        .catch((err, caught) => {
            // Check if the session authentication token is expired.
            if (authToken && err.status == 403) {
                try {
                    var response = JSON.parse(err._body);
                    if (response.error && response.error.code == APIErrorCode.SESSION_AUTH_TOKEN_EXPIRED) {
                        // Login session expired!
                        return Observable.of(response);
                    }
                } catch (e) { }
            }
            // Check incidental bad request.
            if (err.status == 400 && err.statusText == "Bad Request") {
                try {
                    var response = JSON.parse(err._body);
                    if (response.error && response.error.code == 400 && response.error.message
                            && [ "access denied", "bad" ].includes(response.error.message.toLowerCase())) {
                        // Check max attempts.
                        if (attempts < MAX_REQUEST_ATTEMPT) {
                            return this.requestAPIToken().delay(100)
                                    .concatMap(response => this.doPost(api, body, attempts + 1));
                        }
                        console.log("Bad Request, request attempt limit reached!");
                    }
                } catch (e) { }
            }
            return Observable.throw(err);
        });
```

its working fine before i upgraded my angular project, i don't know what to do now

Comment: I guess you are using RxJS v6, right? You must refactor your code to use pipeable operators: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: @MartinAdámek rxjs@5.5.12 this what i get from npm list

Comment: If you are on v5.5, then my answer should help as well, but your problem is in missing `concatMap` operator import to be precise. Either refactor to pipeable operators, or just add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just upgraded angular, you are probably using RxJS v6. If so, you need to refactor to use pipeable operators

Also note you should use `HttpClient` instead of `Http` which is deprecated long time now. Then you can also drop the first map with `response.json()`, as `HttpClient` does that for you automatically.

Keep in mind you need to refactor all observables in your code, not just the one from `HttpClient`, but those with `delay` operator as well.

Take a look here for more info:

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration

```
import { of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, catchError, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

return this.httpClient.post(apiURL, body, options)
    .pipe(
        concatMap(response => {
            // Check if the API_TOKEN is expired.
            if (response.error.code == APIErrorCode.API_TOKEN_EXPIRED || response.error.code == 499) {
                // Expired! Check max attempts.
                if (attempts < MAX_REQUEST_ATTEMPT) {
                    console.log("API_TOKEN expired.");
                    return this.requestAPIToken().pipe(
                        delay(500),
                        concatMap(response => this.doPost(api, body, attempts + 1)
                    );
                }
                console.log("API_TOKEN expired, request attempt limit reached!");
            }
            return of(response);
        }),
        catchError((err, caught) => {
            // Check if the session authentication token is expired.
            if (authToken && err.status == 403) {
                try {
                    var response = JSON.parse(err._body);
                    if (response.error && response.error.code == APIErrorCode.SESSION_AUTH_TOKEN_EXPIRED) {
                        // Login session expired!
                        return of(response);
                    }
                } catch (e) { }
            }
            // Check incidental bad request.
            if (err.status == 400 && err.statusText == "Bad Request") {
                try {
                    var response = JSON.parse(err._body);
                    if (response.error && response.error.code == 400 && response.error.message
                        && [ "access denied", "bad" ].includes(response.error.message.toLowerCase())) {
                        // Check max attempts.
                        if (attempts < MAX_REQUEST_ATTEMPT) {
                            return this.requestAPIToken().pipe(
                                delay(100),
                                concatMap(response => this.doPost(api, body, attempts + 1)
                            );
                        }
                        console.log("Bad Request, request attempt limit reached!");
                    }
                } catch (e) { }
            }
            return throwError(err);
        })
    );
```

If you are on v5.5, then my answer should help as well, but your problem is in missing `concatMap` operator import to be precise. Either refactor to pipeable operators, or just add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';`

This import will monkey patch the `Observable` object with `concatMap` operator - it is not there by default.

More about importing operators in RxJS v5 here:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/concepts/operator-imports.html

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Martin Adámek answer:- 
It should be something like this

```
return this.http.post(apiURL, body, options).pipe(
     map(response => response.json()),
     concatMap(response => {
        //REST OF THE CODE
        return of(response);
    }))
```

Also you don't need to write **Observable.of(response)** now you can simply write **of(response)**
This also applies to **Observable.throw()**

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using RxJS. If you want to combine `map, filter, reduce` etc... Use `.pipe()`

```
return this.http.post(...).pipe(
 map(...).reduce(...)
}))
```

That way you can combine multiple methods.

Comment: No, this is not how you can combine them. Your code is wrong, map operator returns observable, there is no reduce method on it.